# Реализация приложения с обновляемыми формами

Tags: c#, winforms

Стоит задача изменения используемых в приложении форм во время его работы. копал в сторону выгрузки динамических библиотек (чтобы они содержали формы). Т.е. загрузил в `AppDomain` библиотеку, получил нужный

контрол (допустим, что обновлять нужно не только формы) разместил его где нужно, отобразил с его помощью нужные данные.

Получив сигнал о необходимости обновить контрол - свернули всё это хозяйство, выгрузили домен, получили новую версию `DLL`, создали новый домен - и поехали заново.

Проблемы, возникшие по ходу реализации:

1. Вся инфа по работе между доменами ведет к интерфейсам и неким абстрактным классам - а мне нужен хотя бы `System.Forms.Control`.
2. При обмене данными между доменами приложений используется маршаллинг. Используемые контролы имеют всего лишь несколько внешних свойств, которые позволяют их настроить и для получения данных они используют

OracleConnection, который не может быть передан между доменами (он не маршаллится).

т.е. выходит, что подход изначально не верный - загрузка библиотеки в другой домен, создание контрола отображения для данных из oracle-сессии из первого домена.

Как можно реализовать набор таких обновлямых контролов, причем не прерывая соединения с бд, т.е. не выгружая ехе, если это реально?

UPDATE
попробовал передать между доменами

общая библиотека OracleCall.dll
    //интерфейс для класса, через который передаю оригинальный оракловый коннекшн
    public interface IConnectInitializer
    {
        void CreateConnectionClone(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection conn);
    }

вторая библиотека libForNewClasses.dll, содержащая ссылку на общую 
в этой библиотеке реализуется статический хранитель оралового соединения:

```
public class oracleConnInitializer : MarshalByRefObject, IConnectInitializer
{
    public static Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection conn;

    public void CreateConnectionClone(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection connection)
    {
        conn = (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection)connection.Clone();
        conn.Open();
    }
}
```

и контрол:

```
public class newControl : UserControl
{
    private void newControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OracleCall.OraCallProc.getData(oracleConnInitializer.conn);
    }
}
```

третий модуль, ехе-шник, содержит ссылку на первый, общий, чтобы работать с передачей OracleConnection
в нем находится форма, на которую и нужно положить контрол из второй библиотеки.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

// образец соединения
    static Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection conn = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connString);

// домен, куда будем грузить третью библиотеку с дополнительным контролом
    AppDomain dmn;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        init();
    }
    void init()
    {
        // создаем домен
        dmn = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newDomain");

        // загружаем библиотеку с контролом
        Assembly asm = dmn.Load("libForNewClasses");

        // создаем передатчик коннекшена
        IConnectInitializer connInit =
            (IConnectInitializer)
            dmn.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("libForNewClasses", "libForNewClasses.oracleConnInitializer");

        // передаем коннекшн
        connInit.CreateConnectionClone(conn);

        // создаем контрол
        Control ctrl =
            (Control)
            dmn.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("libForNewClasses", "libForNewClasses.newControl");

        this.Controls.Add(ctrl);// пытаемся добавить - БАБАХ! ОШИБКА!!!!
    }
}
```

ОШИБКА: Remoting cannot find field 'parent' on type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.

Что я делаю не так?

UPDATE 2
переделал общую библиотеку. дабы придать ей общий вид обзовем ее common.dll
теперь она содержит образец контрола:
    public class myControls : UserControl
    {
        private Button button1;

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // ...
    }
    public IntPtr _handle { get; set; }
    public void SetParentHandle(IntPtr handle) { _handle = handle; }
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
            createParams.Parent = _handle; // Сюда надо передать Handle формы
            return createParams;
        }
    }
    protected Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection Connection;
    public void InitConnection(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection conn) { Connection = conn; }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        InitializeComponent(); // почему-то без этого не видно
    }
}
```

дочерний контрол также изменил свой код:

```
public class newControl : myControls
{
    private Label label1;

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        InitializeComponent(); // почему-то без этого не видно
        OraCallProc.getData(Connection); // БАБАХ! падаем с ошибкой!     
    }        
}
```

ушел от статического хранения соединения, теперь на главной форме:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // образец соединения
    static Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection conn = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connString);
    // домен, куда будем грузить третью библиотеку с дополнительным контролом
    AppDomain dmn;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        init();
    }
    void init()
    {
        // открываем
        conn.Open();
        // создаем
        dmn = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newDomain");
        // грузим сборку в новый домен
        Assembly asm = dmn.Load("libForNewClasses");
        // создаем контрол
        myControls ctrl =
            (myControls)
            dmn.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("libForNewClasses", "libForNewClasses.newControl");
        // отправляем контролу соединение
        ctrl.InitConnection(conn);
        // устанавливанем хэндл формы
        ctrl.SetParentHandle(this.Handle);
        ctrl.Visible = true;
        ctrl.CreateControl(); // БАБАХ! падаем с ошибкой! (это та, что на OnLoad)
    }
}
```

вопросы:

1) ошибка: Remoting cannot find field 'm_collRef' on type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'.

2) даже если не подключаться к базе, newControl теряет весь свой вид. Почему приходится самому переинициализировать в OnLoad? Не красиво ведь в каждом наследнике переопределять

3) т.е. для каждого типа нового контрола нужно создать наследника (будь то TextEdit, ListView и подобных), даже если нет необходимости подключаться к БД, мне нужен метод SetParentHandle? Как-то это негибко и громоздко получается

Comment: Как System.Windows.Forms.Control, так и OracleConnection наследуют от System.MarshalByRefObject. Это значит, что данные классы можно передавать между доменами приложений напрямую, безо всяких дополнительных интерфейсов.

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить, что в вашем понимании означают слова "не маршаллится" и как вы пробовали делать.

Comment: а цеплять библиотеку с формами как плагин не вариант?

Comment: наверное про маршалинг это я зря, потому что его я не понимаю хоть убей. читал, в-основном, по форумам - отвечали вопросом на вопрос - мол, зачем это надо, пул OracleConnection'ов находится "за AppDomain" (может, это и сбило с пути).

Comment: Зачем вы клонируете соединение с БД, если ваша задача была - избежать этого? И зачем вы делаете отдельный инициализатор соединения - если этот интерфейс можно реализовать сразу в вашем контроле? Статические поля - это плохо!

Comment: @PavelMayorov согласен с последним, скорее было интересно, отклонируется в новом или в старом домене. Так и не понял, потому что дебагом внутрь контрола заходить не хочет. Вообще бы конечно использовать именно то соединение, которое уже открыто

Comment: при попытке передать соединение без клонирования (без этой обертки со статических хранением) в сам контрол, получаю Remoting cannot find field 'm_collRef' on type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'.

Comment: да и с клонированием... видимо, первые разы не вызывал оракловые процедуры, а только открывал соединение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внимание, ответ по 
''Remoting cannot find field 'm_collRef' on type''
Ошибка была не в передаче соединения. С ним работа была налажена. Она крылась в процедуре

```
OraCallProc.getData(Connection);
```

это был статический метод, который выглядел примерно так:

```
public static DataTable getData(OracleConnection conn)
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "TESTSHEME.TESTPROC.GETDATAFUNCTION";
        OracleParameter outvalue = new OracleParameter(); // неправильно! объект создается не в том домене!!!           
        outvalue.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
        outvalue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        outvalue.ParameterName = "OUTP";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(outvalue); // при попытке добавить объект из одного домена к списку параметров команды из другого возникает ошибка с m_colRef

        // вообще и здесь не верно. OracleDataAdapter также создается в другом домене
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);          
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
        da.Fill(dt); // здесь адаптер пытается обратиться к соединению из другого домена, пытается изменить m_state, и тоже падаем
        return dt;

    }
}
```

решить проблему получилось таким образом:

```
public static DataTable getData(OracleConnection conn)
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "TESTSHEME.TESTPROC.GETDATAFUNCTION";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        OracleParameter outvalue = cmd.CreateParameter(); //создается в том же потоке, что и cmd
        outvalue.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
        outvalue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        outvalue.ParameterName = "OUTP";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(outvalue); // поэтому здесь нет ошибки междоменного доступа к внутренним полям
        // OracleDataAdapter не нашел как создать в том же домене, зато есть ExecuteReader
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(OracleDataAdapter.DefaultSourceTableName);
        using (OracleDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < r.FieldCount; i++) dt.Columns.Add(r.GetName(i), r.GetFieldType(i));
            object[] rowValues = new object[r.FieldCount];
            while (r.Read())
            {
                // не нашел метода получения значений всей строки, получаю поштучно
                for (int i = 0; i < r.FieldCount; i++) 
                    // мне нужны "чистые" значения, поэтому DBNull -> null
                    rowValues[i] = object.Equals(r.GetValue(i), DBNull.Value) ? null : r.GetValue(i); 
                dt.Rows.Add(rowValues);
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```

Так что междоменное взаимодействие с OracleConnection вполне реально, надо быть просто внимательнее. Всем спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в дочернем контроле перегрузить свойство CreateParams, куда записать дескриптор родительского контрола:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
        createParams.Parent = ...; // Сюда надо передать Handle формы
        return createParams;
    }
}
```

При этом добавлять такой контрол в коллекцию `Controls` не нужно. Вместо этого надо передать ему свой `Handle`, установить `Visible = true` и вызвать метод `CreateControl()`.

Comment: спасибо, это сработало! но приходится на OnLoad вызывать InitializeComponent()... Не очень круто для наследников, есть ли лекарство от этого?

Comment: @kvvk Сами ищите пути. Тут вы, видимо, первопроходец :)

Comment: @kvvk могу лишь посоветовать сделать отдельный контрол-обертку, куда вынести всю "магию", а основной контрол укладывать внутрь него.

Comment: ну по крайней мере один из вопросов закрыт. мыслей по поводу m_colref нет? вряд ли я единственный, кто пытается передавать коннекшн между доменами, тем более он MarshalByRef... примеров в сети не нашел... ведь есть же хоть какое-то решение

Comment: @kvvk попробуйте сделать свою обертку, которую уже передавать между доменами.

Comment: @kvvk кстати, глянул ваш код... Куда пропали конструкторы? Раньше `InitializeComponent()` вызывался в них!

Comment: @kvvk по пункту номер 3. Метод SetParentHandle нужен в корневом контроле. Те контролы, которые лежать у него внутри, менять не нужно. Да, в ваших интересах уменьшить число корневых контролов, передаваемых между доменами.

Comment: Конструкторы! Действительно, рефаторинг их съел! С ними действительно не нужны лишние вызовы InitializeComponent в OnLoad. По поводу "сделать свою обертку" - это про m_colref? Если да, то можно пояснить? не очень понял ответ...